# Set required fields based on HTTP Verb

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to set an optional [Required] attribute, applicable on PATCH or PUT. I have the following code but no matter what the controller call it will always be required.

```
public class Car
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string CarId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    public string IsIncluded { get; set; }
}
```

Controller;

```
[HttpPatch]
public HttpResponseMessage PatchCar(Car car)
{
    // check if submitted body is valid
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Something is bad!
    }
}
```

What I want is something like the following;

```
public class Car
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string CarId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    [Required(Patch = True, Put = False]
    public string IsIncluded { get; set; }
}
```

Then my ModelState will take the very into account.

I thought about creating separate derived classes for each action (verb), but the code quickly becomes incredibly verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the drawbacks of using data annotations for validation unfortunately they cannot be conditionally added.

There are a number of options to you...

1. Create separate models (or view models) for each verb.
2. Look into something like this.. http://andrewtwest.com/2011/01/10/conditional-validation-with-data-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/ which extends required to be IfRequired and adds conditional validation to data annotations. (You would need to roll your own I should think and it may get clumsy!)
3. Try something like FluentValidation.
   http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/ (this could be a good option depending on your application requirements).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks after spending a day wrestling with this, I've settled on FluentValidation. Seems to work well.