# WebAPI conditional binding based on HTTP verb

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

Take the following class...

```
public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CaseID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

And the following Web API call...

```
    public IHttpActionResult Put(long id, [FromBody] Person person)
```

For a PUT call, we want the model binder to ignore the CaseID property and hydrate Id and FirstName only.

I am considering a custom model binder to pull this off.  So the model binder should pull the HTTP verb (in this case PUT), and if PUT only bind Id and FirstName.  For other verbs bind all properties.

Is there a way to use the default model binder where you can introduce this type of logic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set required fields based on HTTP Verb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940709/set-required-fields-based-on-http-verb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is like using a rock to hammer a nail. It might get the job done, but it's not the right tool. Your model should be a representation of the resource you expect. In other words, if there's a situation where you don't want `CaseID`, then your model *should not have that property*. You can easily solve this with simple inheritance. For example, you could do something like:

```
public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonWithCaseID : Person
{
    public long CaseID { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when you don't want `CaseID`, such as with your PUT method here:

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(long id, [FromBody] Person person)
```

And when you do:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(long id, [FromBody] PersonWithCaseID person)
```

This is much more explicit. It's 100% clear what you're doing, and the API remains self-documenting: you can easily tell that `Put` doesn't accept `CaseID`.